# Scala FileNotFoundException

Tags: scala, cygwin

[image: Screenshot of eror]

While doing I/O in Scala using Cygwin, I have copied data at this location:

```
/cygdrive/c/DataResearch/retail_db/order_items/part-00000
```

but when I am trying to access the file from the Scala prompt with the following command I get this error:

```
val orderItems = Source
  .fromFile("/cygdrive/c/DataResearch/retail_db/order_items/part-00000")
```

**Error:**

```
    java.i[![enter image description here][1]][1]o.FileNotFoundException: \c\DataResearch\retail_db\order_items\part-
    00000                                                                                                                 
    (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
  at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:91)
  at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:76)
  at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:54)
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Provide path as C:\\abc\def\\new.

Comment: Thanks , Got it !

Comment: You can launch a JVM from Cygwin, but doing so doesn't cause the JVM to understand Cygwin-style paths.